# keyboard takes time for starting before login

Tags: keyboard, suspend, login-screen, xinput, input-devices

I have installed ubuntu 20.04.3 on my hp laptop. Every time I try to login after suspend or sometimes even after boot it takes a long time for my laptop inbuilt keyboard to start. I have to wait sometime for it to start and after that keyboard functions normally during the whole session. I have tried wireless keyboard and it works normally.
This is my `xinput list` output:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA32AD:00 06CB:CD50 Touchpad            id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA32AD:00 06CB:CD50 Mouse               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023       id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Wireless Mouse PID:4022          id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023       id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

and `dmesg |grep i8042` gives following

```
[    0.879039] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    0.879041] i8042: PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX port disabled, if this is  incorrect please boot with i8042.nopnp
[    0.880525] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    0.953762] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
[ 1217.542196] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input38
[ 3499.262886] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input177
```

and `dmesg |grep keyboard` gives following

```
[    0.953762] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
[    1.625816] systemd[1]: Starting Set the console keyboard layout...
[    1.659009] systemd[1]: Finished Set the console keyboard layout.
[ 1217.542196] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input38
[ 3499.262886] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input177
```

Can someone please help me solve this issue because I'm constantly facing this issue while logging in to the computer.

Comment: What is a long time?

Comment: Time is not fixed its usually 20-30 sec and sometime even a minute or two.